# Redis's message broker, when to use

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka, redis, publish-subscribe

I have been reading about message broker lately and recently found Redis also has its own message broker just like RabbitMQ, Kafka, beanstalk etc. Redis also has pub/sub mechanism built-in.

I am also a hardcore socket.io user, so what I am confused about it:

1. Is Redis's message broker works in the similar manner as others like RabbitMQ, Kafka, beanstalk?
2. When to use a Message Broker vs Pub/Sub vs socket.io? Please share example if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have done R&Ds by using the Kafka message system and Redis.

Kafka is a distributed, partitioned, and replicated commit log service that provides a messaging functionality as well as a unique design.

[Please refer to this article](https://javamastermind.com/2020/11/01/apache-kafka/)

Redis is a bit different from Kafka in terms of its storage and various functionalities. At its core, Redis is an in-memory data store that can be used as a high-performance database and a cache. It is perfect for real-time data processing.
The various data structures supported by Redis are strings, hashes, lists, sets, and sorted sets.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question about Redis Streams or pub/sub